# Sharepoint developer training for a company new to Office 365

Tags: development, office-365-developer

Sorry for the long question but I want to give you the background. I'm asking for training suggestions for beginning developers.

My company is consolidating and moving to Office 365 from a mix of other (Microsoft and non Microsoft) platforms. We have three developers (including myself) that will be using Sharepoint to build an intranet including various "out of the box" Sharepoint features. Eventually, once we find our feet, we will move to creating more custom applications.

I, for one, have zero Sharepoint experience. The other developers have some, but not in the cloud environment. We have agreed that we want to start with some very basic training to get us off on the right foot. I want to learn all the basics of the "out of the box" functionality before I get into using visual studio. I would consider the free online courses but our management *wants* us to get some more official training.

This course: "SharePoint 2013 Site Collection and Site Administration" (#55033) looks about right, but it is only available "live on line" any time in the near future. I think live online is sort of the worst of both worlds: 1) No live instructor experience and 2) can't rewind or pause on-line experience.

The live online class is $3000 per person. I would think that for $9000, we could pay someone to come to us and show us how things work in person for a few days. Does this sound like a reasonable idea? If so, do you recommend any companies that do this?

There may be other options as well. Does anyone have any suggestions for us? Thank you in advance for your time in reading this rather long question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are lots of companies offering training in person. Googling in your area will no doubt get you some results. If you are experienced devs already you can't go wrong with Pluralsight: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/sharepoint-2013-fundamentals. This will let you learn at your own pace and then skip to dev training as and when needed for both the app model and on prem.